# XACML Editor using <Condition> and String Comparison

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

Referring to the implementation of the `<condition>` logic (true/false) in the WSO2 editor. why does XACML Version 3 polices editor reject any other string oriented compare function, except the use of "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in" ?

**Example: Accepted syntax**

```
<Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule1">
  <Target></Target>
   <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myGroup</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" AttributeId="http://w3.red.com/subject/groupsUserBelong" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
      ..
```

**Example of  syntax causing error:**  all other string comparison function, including REGEX function:

```
     <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule1">
       <Target></Target>
         <Condition>
             <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-contains">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myGroup</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" AttributeId="http://w3.red.com/subject/groupsUserBelong" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                </Apply>
             </Apply>
          </Condition>
          ..
```

The present error often cause a need to revert the the general policy scheme moving from a "Deny" effect to a "Permit" effect, in combination with a "match" logic, which is not welcome from a developer standpoint, as the "Deny" rules use to have a much richer functionality like detailed ObligationExpressions for error handling. To apply the `<Condition>` statement use to produce more comprehensive code in this situation.

I appreciate to get an advice how to use `<Condition>` statement together with general String comparison functions, like:

```
. urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal
. urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-contains
. urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match
. urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-equal-ignore-case
```

or other String related operation that generate a boolean outcome.

Trying to achieve the same logic with ALFA, here the source:

```
namespace com.red.XACML {
    import Attributes.*
    import attributes.*
    import com.red.XACML.Attributes.*

    rule notBGroups { 
            deny
        }
    rule bGroupsCobMail {
        target 
    condition
        stringOneAndOnly(subjectAttributes.groupsUserBelong)=="myGroup"
        permit

    }

    policy bGroups { 
        apply firstApplicable
        bGroupsCobMail
        notBGroups
            }       
        }
```

This also throws the same error message as via WSO2 Try-It function:

```
<Result>
<Decision>Indeterminate</Decision>
<Status>
<StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:processing-error"/>
<StatusMessage>urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only expects a bag that contains a single element, got a bag with 7 elements</StatusMessage>
</Status>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myname@red.com</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Result>
</Response>
```

Looks like the AttributeDesignator bag needs another cycle of iterations to be able to parse the elements. How we can achieve this?

**Latest update:** 
Got into some circle here, not haveing advance in the testing due to syntax rejection at the WSO2 XML editor.

The issue is that the Attribute Designator for the AttributeID "http://w3.red.com/subject/groupsUserBelong" 
returns a list of seven elements. The seven elements reflects all data for the subject, so logically the value of 7 makes sense.

My logic is as follows: I have defined a group name variable, indeed a String like "myGroup", then I need to iterate the 7 elements of the 
LinkedHashSet returning from the PIP, relevant or not, and scan each of the elements searching for a pattern (or word) like "myGroup". Once found 
equality, a boolean "true" is set as outcome. Now at outer section of the condition, I plan to add a NOT function to reverse the boolean state so the condition will generate a "Deny" case the group is not found, by this trigger the ObligationEpression with detailed error messages.

Looks like the core issue is how to iterate the list of seven elements and how to find the word inside one element as the string-subset is 
not finding the word and other functions are not accepted.

```
 <Condition> 
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not"> 
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"> 
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only"> 
                  <AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" AttributeId="http://w3.ibm.com/subject/groupsUserBelong" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator> 
               </Apply> 
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myGroup</AttributeValue> 
            </Apply> 
         </Apply> 
      </Condition> 

<Result>
<Decision>Indeterminate</Decision>
<Status>
<StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:processing-error"/>
<StatusMessage>urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only expects a bag that contains a single element, got a bag with 7 elements</StatusMessage>
</Status>

   <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not">
            <!--Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-subset"-->
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myGroup</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://w3.ibm.com/subject/groupsUserBelong" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Apply>
            </Apply>
         </Condition>
<Result>
<Decision>Deny</Decision>
 Conclusion: the condition did not find the group.
```

Other syntax constructions are rejected by the editor by this message:

```
Entitlement policy is not updated. Error is :Unsupported Entitlement Policy. Policy can not be parsed
```

**Latest Update:** 
This behaviour looks like a bug in the WSO2 Policy XML Editor. The tool misses support for:

A.3.12 Higher-order bag functions

for example: sample any-of-any

for supported logic see: 
http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html

The issue can be simulated with the following "Condition" statements:

```
<Condition>
      <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of-any">
            <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myGroup</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myGroup</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
            </Apply>
      </Condition>
```

Comment: Hi Claude, doesn't the editor tell you why? String-contains works on atomic values, not bags of values. An attribute designator is a bag. That's why it's not working.

Comment: @David Brossard, in a logical view your explanation makes sense and by printing it, indeed the  attribute designator is a bag, in my test case its a list of 7 elements that are part of the custom PIP AttributeFinder return object. So how can I reference only one single field like the one described as 
AttributeId=http://w3.red.com/subject/groupsUserBelong, and not the entire bag? 

Looks like my issue is how to address and load the Attribute from the PIP return object.

Comment: Use the string-one-and-only function

Comment: @David Brossard, thanks for the hint. Looks like our AttributeDesignator object is in a nested format, see the details in the editor section above, throwing an unexpected error message: "string-one-and-only expects a bag that contains a single element, got a bag with 7 elements."

Comment: Claude, read my response carefully. I think your issue comes from the fact you confuse attribute designators which are always bags of values with atomic values. When you write stringOneAndOnly(a), this means a must contain a single value - no more, no less. If you want to compare http://w3.red.com/subject/groupsUserBelong to a list of allowed groups then use stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(http://w3.red.com/subject/groupsUserBelong, allowedGroups) or use a higher-order function e.g. AnyOfAny

Comment: Claude, ALFA always produces valid XACML 3.0. If Balana cannot take it then it has a bug

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare 2 bags, e.g.

- userCitizenship
- allowedCitizenships

you can do the following:

#### Case #1

- userCitizenship is single-valued
- allowedCitizenships is single-valued

You can use `stringOneAndOnly(userCitizenship)==stringOneAndOnly(allowedCitizenships)`

#### Case #2

- userCitizenship is single-valued
- allowedCitizenships is multi-valued

(or the other way round)

1. You can use `stringIsIn(stringOneAndOnly(userCitizenship), allowedCitizenships)`.
2. You can also use a higher-order function e.g. anyOf or allOf as follows `anyOf(function[stringEquals], allowedCitizenships, stringOneAndOnly(userCitizenship))`.

#### Case #3

- Both bags are multi-valued.

  Here are your options:

  1. You can use `stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(userCitizenship, allowedCitizenships)`. This functions works on bags.
  2. You can use a higher-order function `AnyOfAny(function[stringEquals], userCitizenship, allowedCitizenships)`.

There are many more higher-order functions you can use in XACML to achieve the exact behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I've tried to create an  XML source by ALFA following your recommendations for case 1,2 and 3, but still having rejection of the entire policy by the WSO2 XML editor. I've validated the code against the V3 schema and it was declared as valid. Please check the details in the samples printed above. Looks like the core issue is at the iteration inside the <Condition> logic section.

Comment: Our testing points to the implementation of a function described in the XACML Version 3 specification. A.3.12 Higher-order bag functions - any-of-any (see details and code sample above). Its use generates the error message:  "Entitlement policy is not updated. Error is :Unsupported Entitlement Policy. Policy can not be parsed".